# How to use this script?

Tags: c#, c, windows, compiler-construction, hard-drive

Someone very helpful over on superuser wrote this script for me, the purpose of it is to wipe specific sectors on a running windows HDD with zeros. Here's the code:

http://pastebin.com/LwYFxhFS

I am not sure how to compile that and run it? Would i need to use like visual studio express and compile it then run it from cmd line? Also i am not sure if it will work as windows 7 basically stops any program (like hex editors) from messing with the HDD while it is the one in use.

> You can just run it like:
>
> wipe \.\PhysicalDrive0 0 512
> where the first argument is the file name, the second is the offset, and the third is the >number of bytes. The number of bytes probably can't be over ~63 MiB.

Of course i wouldn't input 0 and 512 as that looks to delete the MBR.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I apologize, i know i am basically asking to be spoon fed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.
1) Never compile code that you can't read, that code could easily wipe your entire hard drive with zeros (on purpose, or by accident).
2) Look at Eraser, does the same thing, but has been tested well.

Though to answer you question, yes visual studio C++ express should compile that.

Alright, lets break this down.  You can compile the program use visual studio.  Visual studio is an IDE (development environment) that allows you to write code easily.  There are other compilers if you would like to use them instead.  The entire idea is to make this code an executable.
To do this you need to do the following:

1. Download [Visual C++ 2010 express][1], and install
2. Start the program, click new project
3. Click Win32 Console Application
4. Name it something (like wipe, but it doesn't matter the name
5. Click finish
6. Paste this code (a bit modified for the pre compiled headers, to lazy to tell you to uncheck that box). http://pastebin.com/c3gZ3bct
7. Click the button F6
8. This should show that the code was compiled successfully (don't worry about the warnings)
9. There should be a tab on the right that says "Solution Explorer", open that.  Right click on the name of the project (in my example it should be wipe), and click "Open Folder in windows explorer"
10. Go up one folder, then click on Debug.
11. There will be a file in there with the name of the project, and it is an executable.  This is your program.
12. Open up cmd, navigate to this folder (type 'cd {folder path}' to get there), and then use the example the coder gave you to use his code.

Fell free to ask if part of this doesn't make sense, give me the step you are on, and why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: As i know eraser can't wipe a specific sector, it's just for files or free space.

Comment: Hm, I see the difference, why would you wipe a sector?

Comment: The why isn't important its the how. It's just 512 bytes beginning at offset 31744 from the physical drive (sector 62).

Comment: I suppose you could format with say fdisk (linux), I'll guess it's a code of some kind that needs to be stored on the drive?  I would recommend posting it on a board (maybe this one, you will need to read the rules here first though, to make sure), and ask them to validate the code.  Though my answer above is correct, that looks like C++ (which I am not familiar with), so compiling it in visual studio C++ express should do it. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express

Comment: Oh, and what he most likely meant was the compiled version (on the command line).  I confirmed this works (not the program, the compiling of the program).

Comment: You mean boot up a linux live cd and use dd... but im not sure how to use the dd command. Something like dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1 bs=512 count=1 offeset= 31744 ?

Comment: I compiled it to and the program doesnt appear to work... well i ran it from the cmd line and hit return... nothing happened. Your  gonna get the green tick but i'm still stuck on this ha.

Comment: Darn, just spent a few minutes typing how to do it.  Try the instructions above (just start at 3 if you already have visual studio)

Comment: I will try visual studio as per your instructions thanks, i used an online compiler before.

Comment: hm, I see, online compilers have their issues sometimes (though they are great for group projects).  There are other options of course, but I'm most familiar with visual studio, it just makes life a bit easier most of the time.

Comment: It doesn't work...   http://imagebin.org/160001    it just returns a new line and nothing changed on the HDD... maybe i'm doing something wrong or need use a different name for the drive? Winhex calls it HD0

Comment: hm, try a few things, rename the executable to `wipe` (if you can see the .exe, rename it to `wipe.exe`).  Then type the command as follows `wipe.exe Afile.txt 31744 512`, if you can see, you need to specify a file, and `\.` is the current directory (don't know how that would work here.  Also, I'm not sure what you mean by `PhysicalDrive0` (not sure that notation works in windows).

Comment: I'm a bit scared to try wipe.ext PhysicalDrive0 31744 512     as i just think the guy who wrote it probably put the back slashes in for a reason.

Comment: exe*, and unless I know what you are trying todo, this trouble shooting could go on for a while :/.  Hm, if you are trying to wipe part of a drive, I would look into fpart a bit closer, seems to do what you would want.  This program looks to wipe part of a file.

Comment: using a live linux dvd would be easy but i just wanted a way to do it from within windows. But it might be impossible. Sector 62 is in track 0 of the physical HDD so its not even part of the system partition.

Comment: The program you have above looks like it will only work on a file (not  a partition/drive).  You might want to confer with the coder (I could be completely wrong), the program does specifically ask for a file though.  Otherwise, fpart would be the way to go.  Or come up with a better way then this (maybe truecrypt or something).

Comment: fpart you mean fdisk... which would need a live cd to boot.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes fdisk.  I believe you mean gparted when you say livecd, fdisk comes on many live cds (including ubuntu).  I just used it today, and it has choices to choose where to start formatting, and how far to format.  It might not do what you want, but I doubt there are many things that will (hence the custom coded program).